# Images randomly disappears from browser view

Tags: css, image, url, flexbox, background-image

I just started learning CSS and I need your help.

I started to write the code and everything looked correct and beautiful, images were on place. Then I took a 20min pause, came back to the pc, browser refreshed and all the images (two img) just disappeared from viewing.

Can you please advice what may be a problem?

```
.logo-image {
    display: block;
    width: 6rem;
    height: 6rem;
    background-image: url(/resources/img/icons8-leaf-96.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    opacity: 90%;
}

    .banner {
    background-image: url(/resources/img/banner-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    padding-top: 15rem;
    padding-bottom: 15rem;
    color: #4A6C6F;
}
```

Also if I try this, nothing changes:

```
background-image: url(resources/img/icons8-leaf-96.png);
```

Thank you!

I tried to remove and then add "/", tried to add img again, restarted the program and browser, only 1 img is appearing again (logo), but the banner bg is empty

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of a image.

Comment: Hope now its fine

Comment: Please add the HTML; perhaps as a code snippet with the CSS (there is a snippet button when you edit)

Comment: Consider putting quotes (string) for the url as demonstrated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: You have tagged "flexbox" but there is no flexbox in the provided CSS; consider enhancing with a more reproducible example.